# AngularJs Get empty

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to retrieve data sent by my server (JSON file). but why is it it's not printing in my browser?

Here's the code.

newsfeed.js

```
var newsfeed = angular.module('newsfeed',[]);
newsfeed.controller('newsfeedController',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.posts = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost/must_sns/main/all_status').success(function(data){
                $scope.posts = data;
        }); 
    }
});
```

html

```
<div ng-app="newsfeed" ng-controller="newsfeedController">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <p>{{post.body}}</p>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Sorry, I not quite familiar with angular.

Comment: There could be numerous possibilities, does the call even go through? Does the data look like what you  think it is? Do you initiate the call by invoking posts method? You have invalid html as well, Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't get any errors from the console. Also, when I view the url `http://localhost/must_sns/main/all_status` from the browser I can see JSON data. I don't know what happen when presenting data using angularjs

Comment: You will know if you debug.. :)

Comment: Do `console.log(data);` in your `$http.get()` and provide your output

Comment: I already do console.log(data); but nothing is in my console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting $scope.posts to a function first, but you are not calling that function. This means your $http request is never getting called. Try:

```
newsfeed.controller('newsfeedController',function($scope,$http){
     var getPosts = function(){
        $http.get('http://localhost/must_sns/main/all_status').success(function(data){
                $scope.posts = data;
        }); 
    }
    getPosts(); // need to call the function
});
```

(or you can ditch the getPosts function and just call $http.get directly, but it's good to keep it in a function in case you need to call it again later.)

Comment: Thanks, it is now working. I even got data using console.log(data) but in my first attempt get no result. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Port8080 My first comment `Do you initiate the call by invoking posts method?` :)